# File picker not displaying text files

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to pick a text file with a file picker. I am getting this error alert `No apps can perform this action` . My code is:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("*/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

It also doesn't display text files if I use `intent.setType("*/*");`. How should I fix my problem?

Comment: Try intent..setType("text/plain")

Comment: Remove the `Intent.createChooser()` part. Just call `startActivtyForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);`.